# How do you conduct a power analysis for logistic regression in R?

Tags: r

I'm familiar with G*Power as a tool for power analyses, but have yet to find a resource on the internet describing how to compute a power analysis for for logistic regression in R. The pwr package doesn't list logistic regression as an option.

Answer (score 5):

You will very likely need to "roll your own".

- Specify your hypothesized relationship between predictors and outcome.
- Specify what values of your predictors you are likely to observe in your study. Will they be correlated?
- Specify the effect size you would like to detect, e.g., odds ratios corresponding to two specific settings of your predictors.
- Specify a power level, e.g., beta=0.80.
- For different sample sizes n:

  - Simulate predictors as specified
  - Simulate outcomes
  - Run your analysis
  - Record whether you detect a statistically significant effect
  - Do these steps many times, on the order of 1000 or more times. Count how often you did detect an effect. If you detected an effect more than (e.g.) 80% of the time, you are overpowered - reduce n and start over. If you detected an effect less than 80%, you are underpowered - increase n and start over. Rinse & repeat until you have a good n.

And then think some more about whether all your assumptions really make sense. Vary them a bit. Is the resulting value of n sensitive to your assumptions?

Yes, this will be quite a bit of work. But it will be worth it. On the one hand, it will keep you from running an over- or underpowered study. On the other hand, as I wrote, this will force you to think deeply about your assumptions, and this is the path to enlightenment. (Which is a painful path to travel. Sorry.)

If you don't get any better answers specifically helping you to do this in R, you may want to look to [CrossValidated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions) for more help. Good luck!

Answer (score 3):

[This question and answers](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/35940/simulation-of-logistic-regression-power-analysis-designed-experiments/36040#36040) on Crossvalidated discuss power for logistic regression and include R code as well as additional discussion and links for more information.